# How do I get the price chainlink price feed when testin with hardhat?

Tags: ether, hardhat, testing, chainlink

I have written a smart contract utilizing the chainlink price feed.
Now I want to test if the prices which I calculate in my smart contract are correct.

In solidity I fetch the current USD / ETH price like this:

```
priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
(,int value,, ,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
...
```

But how would I fetch the current ETH value in the JavaScript testing file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two main options, fork mainnet, or use a mockPriceFeed. You can see examples across different frameworks in the [smart contract starter kits](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/starter-kits) repo.

## Mock Price Feed

[Example](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/hardhat-starter-kit/blob/main/contracts/PriceConsumerV3.sol)

Deploy your contract with a variable address for a price feed.

```js
    constructor(address _priceFeed) {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceFeed);
    }
```

In your tests, deploy a mock price feed and then use that address as input for your contract.

Hardhat example:

```js
      beforeEach(async () => {
        await deployments.fixture(["mocks", "feed"])
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContract("MockV3Aggregator")
        priceConsumerV3 = await ethers.getContract("PriceConsumerV3")
      })
```

## Fork Mainnet

For forking mainnet, you'd just read the price of the mainnet contract and compare it to the price returned by your contract.

```js
const price = await myContract.getPrice()
const priceFromFeed = await priceFeed.getPrice()
assert.equal(price.toString(), priceFromFeed.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fork the mainnet with an Infura key (or Alchemy key) and hardhat and do your tests?

Here is a link to hardhat's page explaining how to do it.

https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But I wonder how does the actual implementation of the testing look like. How do I query the ETH to USD price in my test file?