# Contract is not deploying locally while testing for testcases

Tags: solidity, hardhat, testing, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to write test cases for my code, here the MockV3Aggregator is supposed to run locally, upon deploying it works fine but when I try to only run the test case it seems that the MockV3Aggregator does not deploy, and with out deploying the deployment tries to fetch the contract address.

I am using deployments. fixture to make sure the specific code is deployed.

Here is the test case code

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers } = require("hardhat")

describe("Testing of the Commit Solidity program",async function(){
    let mocksv3aggregator;
    let commit; 
    beforeEach(async function(){
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"])
        console.log("The fixture is crossed")
        mocksv3aggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        // commit = await ethers.getContract("Comitment")
    })

    describe("testing mock script", async function () {
        it("set the aggregator address correctly", async function () {
            const response = await mocksv3aggregator.priceFeed()
            console.log(response)
            asset.equal(response,response.address)
        })
    })
})
```

Here is the MockV3Aggregator code to deploy it

```
const {network,hre} = require("hardhat")

const DECIMAL_VALUE = 8
const INITIAL_VALUE = 20000000000
module.exports = async(hre) =>{
    const {getNamedAccounts,deployments} = hre;
    const {deploy,log} = deployments
    const {deployer} = await getNamedAccounts()

    const networkChainID = await network.config.chainId 

    if(networkChainID === 31337){
        log("Deploying the MOCKV3AGGREAGATOR")
        await deploy("MockV3Aggregator",{
            from:deployer,
            log:true,
            args:[DECIMAL_VALUE,INITIAL_VALUE]
        })
    }
}

module.exports.tag = ["all","mocks"]
```

here is the solidity code for the MOCKV2Aggregator.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
```

The error that I receive

```
 0 passing (3s)
  1 failing

  1) Testing of the Commit Solidity program
       "before each" hook for "set the aggregator address correctly":
     Error: No deployment found for: MockV3Aggregator
      at Object.get (node_modules\hardhat-deploy\src\DeploymentsManager.ts:162:17)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\uint\Commit.test.js:11:29)
```

> I am running "npx hardhat test"

> I am using hardhat-deploy plugin in order to deploy.

Comment: this might help https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/137169/how-do-i-get-the-price-chainlink-price-feed-when-testin-with-hardhat

Comment: Yep, tired it as well, it did not work.